# than how possible to call all Class class methods like hashCode() using any Inteface refrence variable?

Tags: java, object, interface

*AS i know, We can use Interface refrence to hold its implementing class Object and by using that refrence variable we can call only method inside that interface or its super Interface methods which is overriden by its child implementing class ..*

**my doubt is, how possible to call all Class class methods like hashCode() using that Interface refrence variable ??              as Object  class is root class(extended by class) if we call any method of Object class like hashCode(),... using any class refrence  we can access all Object methods.. but how possible using any Interface refrence variable ??**

```
package hemantdhanuka;


public interface Interf {
    void m1();
    void m2();
    void m3();

}
```

implemng child class

```
public class SubInterf implements Interf{
@Override
public void m1() {
System.out.println(" i am overridden m1() method");
}

@Override
public void m2() {
System.out.println(" i am overridden m1() method");    
}

@Override
public void m3() {
System.out.println(" i am overridden m1() method");
}
public void m4(){
System.out.println("i am m4() new method of SubInterf ");
}
public static void main(String[] args){
Interf i=new SubInterf();
i.m1();
i.m3();
//i.m4();// i know its not possible
i.hashCode();**why it is not showing error ??**         
 }
}
```

Comment: why do you think it should show an error?

Comment: `using any class refrence we can access all Object methods.. but how possible using any Interface refrence variable`  its the same way you called `m1()` and `m3()` on `i`